# Using Multiple Unique rows to create different Excel Workbooks from Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hoping to use Python to use multiple combine multiple values in a single column into its own workbook - basically, grouping a few unique values together.

Input:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'nick', 'jack'],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
```

Goal Output: Edited slightly: I would like this to result in 2 new workbooks: Tom's information in one, with Nick and Jack in another.

I'm pretty new to Python so I haven't tried much that is useful. I was able to create multiple worksheets based on unique values, but I would need to 1) Adjust to workbooks, opposed to worksheets, and 2) I would like to combine some of the unique values into the same workbook.

```
df1_dict={}

for name in df1['name'].unique():
   name_df1 = df1[df1['name'] == name]
    df1_dict[name] =  name
```

Comment: Could you please add your expected output?

Comment: I think it's in there

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do using `for` loop with pandas:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    for name in data['Name'].unique():
        df = data[data['Name'] == name]
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```

This outputs a `output.xlsx` file having three sheets.

To output to three different files, you can do:

```
for name in data['Name'].unique():
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{name}.xlsx') as writer:      
        df = data[data['Name'] == name]
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I do have two followup questions.

1) Is it possible to output to three different excel files instead of three sheets within one file?
2) Is it possible to rename the files through Python? Some of the unique names have invalid characters or are >31 characters.

Comment: @Jvass001 Please check the edit. You can remove the invalid names or fix it in the dataframe before saving them to a file.